# How can you pull strings from a webpage and display them?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, weather

I want to make a desktop weather application in C#. I want it to pull the weather from weather.com. I am very new to this subject. I am using the HtmlAgilityPack.dll. I have tried the following code to pull today's weather (degrees):

```
string webUrl = "http://www.weather.com/weather/today/l/90025:4:US";
HtmlWeb HTMLweb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = HTMLweb.Load(webUrl);
string degrees = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"wx-local-wrap\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div/section/section[1]/div[2]/span[1]/span")[0].InnerText;
MessageBox.Show("{0}°F", degrees);
```

However, when I run this code it throws the NullReferenceException. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Clearly your node cannot be found

Comment: Have you checked the value of 'doc' after it is assigned? The node you're looking for must not be there. Consider using a public API instead, there are many which will return you a formatted XML document that you can parse.

Comment: Please show the HTML content you'd like to find.

Comment: You might check the legality of what you're doing in their TOS. Scraping data from their site might not be something they're okay with. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling webpages like this is an exhaustive task and any change to the webpage by its developers will render your application useless.

Therefore, use XML or an API to retrieve weather data instead. This can be a good place to start:

http://openweathermap.org/current

It supports XML and JSON where you provide parameters such as cityID, cityName or a geographic coordinates and it returns results in clear structured XML easy to parse using [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

Hope that helped :)